# Handling possible nil in return func?

Tags: ios, swift, return

I have a func where I want to return a configured `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

The issue is that if I can't construct a document URL, I want to return, but can't as the func needs to return the viewer. How can I edit this function so that the func returns the viewer if the URL was valid or exists if it's not...

```
func saveBase64StringToPDF(base64String: String, title: String) -> UIDocumentInteractionController {
    guard var documentsURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last,
          let convertedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)
        else {
            return // issue is here
    }

    documentsURL.appendPathComponent(title)

    do {
        try convertedData.write(to: documentsURL)
    } catch {
        print("FAILED TO WRITE")
    }
    let interactionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: documentsURL)
    return interactionController
}
```

Comment: just make at as func saveBase64StringToPDF(base64String: String, title: String) -> UIDocumentInteractionController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the return value **optional**.

```
func saveBase64StringToPDF(base64String: String, title: String) -> UIDocumentInteractionController? {
    guard var documentsURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last,
          let convertedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    documentsURL.appendPathComponent(title)

    do {
        try convertedData.write(to: documentsURL)
    } catch {
        print("FAILED TO WRITE")
    }

    let interactionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: documentsURL)
    return interactionController
}
```

Comment: But it's better to make function throwing, and throw proper error, explaining why it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIDocumentInteractionController?` in the return type of method declaration instead of `UIDocumentInteractionController`

The `?` next to any class or object tells the compiler that it is optional. An optional may contain a value or nil.